# ¿Como unir multiples registros con variables similares por id en mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto pequeño de inventario, la base del problema es que existen registros de productos donde dicho producto puede estar en 2 bodegas al mismo tiempo, el diagrama es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo existen 2 bodegas, por lo cual el producto puede estar en las 2 y se almacenan esos registros en la tabla inventario.

Tengo una vista inicial de la siguiente manera:

```
create or replace view `lista_productos` as
select
    `tipo_producto`.`Nombre` as `Tipo_Producto`,
    `producto`.`id_Producto` as `Id_Producto`,
    `producto`.`Cod_Producto` as `Codigo_Producto`,
    `producto`.`Nombre` as `Nombre_Producto`,
    `producto`.`Cantidad_Producto` as `Cantidad_Producto`,
    `producto`.`Descripcion` as `Descripcion_Producto`,
    `producto`.`Estado` as `Estado_Producto`,
    `inventario`.`id_Inventario` as `Id_Inventario`,
    `inventario`.`Cantidad` as `Inventario_Bodega`,
    `bodega`.`Nombre` as `Nombre_Bodega`
from
    (((`inventario`
join `bodega` on
    ((`bodega`.`id_Bodega` = `inventario`.`Bodega_id_Bodega`)))
join `producto` on
    ((`producto`.`id_Producto` = `inventario`.`Producto_id_Producto`)))
join `tipo_producto` on
    ((`tipo_producto`.`id_Tipo_Producto` = `producto`.`Tipo_Producto_id_Tipo_Producto`)));
```

Eso me retorna los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como existe siempre productos que puede llegar a tener multiples registros "en esta caso maximo 2", lo que busco es tener una vista con los registros agrupados que sean iguales. Con lo cual realice la siguiente vista:

```
create or replace view lista_producto_V2 as
select  tipo_producto.Nombre as Tipo_Producto,
        producto.id_Producto as Id_Producto,
        producto.Cod_Producto as Codigo_Producto,
        producto.Nombre as Nombre_Producto,
        producto.Cantidad_Producto as Cantidad_Producto,
        producto.Descripcion as Descripcion_Producto,
        producto.Estado as Estado_Producto,
        (select inventario.id_Inventario from inventario where inventario.Producto_id_Producto = producto.id_Producto and inventario.Bodega_id_Bodega = bodega.id_Bodega and bodega.Nombre = 'INSUMOS RAPIDOS') as Id_Inventario1,
        (select inventario.Cantidad from inventario where inventario.Producto_id_Producto = producto.id_Producto and inventario.Bodega_id_Bodega = bodega.id_Bodega and bodega.Nombre = 'INSUMOS RAPIDOS') as Inv_Bodega1,
        (select inventario.id_Inventario from inventario where inventario.Producto_id_Producto = producto.id_Producto and inventario.Bodega_id_Bodega = bodega.id_Bodega and bodega.Nombre = 'BODEGA') as Id_Inventario2,
        (select inventario.Cantidad from inventario where inventario.Producto_id_Producto = producto.id_Producto and inventario.Bodega_id_Bodega = bodega.id_Bodega and bodega.Nombre = 'BODEGA') as Inv_Bodega2
from
    inventario
inner join bodega on bodega.id_Bodega = inventario.Bodega_id_Bodega
inner join producto on producto.id_Producto = inventario.Producto_id_Producto
inner join tipo_producto on tipo_producto.id_Tipo_Producto = producto.Tipo_Producto_id_Tipo_Producto
```

La segunda vista la cree con subconsultas, esto me acerco mas a lo que busco, la cual me retorna los siguiente registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien las 6 primeras columnas en datos son iguales las ultimas 4 son diferentes, lo que busco es poder agrupar los registros que sean iguales por el Id_Producto, para así obtener un registro de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen de salida esta editada en excel, el ideal seria que la vista quede directamente con los datos agrupados, pero con una consulta a la vista que me retorne el ideal seria suficiente, el nombre de la vista es lista_productos_v2.

Estoy trabajando con mysql y no me permite usar pivot, me toca crear manualmente el proceso con sum pero realmente no me funciona, algun idea o solucion?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la consulta SQL que estas haciendo?, ¿o es solo un simple SELECT?

Comment: Realice una modificación al post con mas especificaciones y con código para ser entendible.

Comment: Me parece que lo que quieres podría hacerse en una sola consulta SQL. Pero creo que estás demasiado centrado en las vistas... eso no es lo importante. Lo importante es la consulta y luego cuando la consulta funcione, **si está justificado** la metes en una vista. ¿Podrías explicar con la mayor simplicidad posible lo que quieres exactamente, olvidándote de las vistas?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno gente al final entre consultas, toqueteos y pruebas, logre conseguir el resultado, realmente la segunda lista que cree "lista_productos_v2" es ideal para usar pivot puesto que me permite pasar las filas a las columnas, pero debido a que trabajo con mysql no es posible.

Lo que realice al final fue trabajar con la primera lista donde tenia registros repetidos, y filtrar con max() por datos especificos y agrupar para evitar los registros repetidos.

```
select Tipo_Producto, Id_Producto, Codigo_Producto, Nombre_Producto, Cantidad_Producto, Descripcion_Producto, Estado_Producto,
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'INSUMOS RAPIDOS', Id_Inventario , 0)) as Id_Inv1,
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'INSUMOS RAPIDOS', Inventario_Bodega , 0)) as Inv_bodega1,
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'BODEGA', Id_Inventario , 0)) as Id_Inv2, 
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'BODEGA', Inventario_Bodega , 0)) as Inv_bodega2 
from lista_productos
group by Tipo_Producto, Id_Producto, Codigo_Producto, Nombre_Producto, Cantidad_Producto, Descripcion_Producto, Estado_Producto;
```

La salida de esa consulta es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la solución a lo que buscaba y es lo mas optimo para lo que buscaba. Cabe resaltar que si la consulta no tiene el group by solo retorna un registro.

Ej:

```
select Tipo_Producto, Id_Producto, Codigo_Producto, Nombre_Producto, Cantidad_Producto, Descripcion_Producto, Estado_Producto,
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'INSUMOS RAPIDOS', Id_Inventario , 0)) as Id_Inv1,
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'INSUMOS RAPIDOS', Inventario_Bodega , 0)) as Inv_bodega1,
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'BODEGA', Id_Inventario , 0)) as Id_Inv2, 
    max(if(Nombre_Bodega = 'BODEGA', Inventario_Bodega , 0)) as Inv_bodega2 
from lista_productos
```

salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero os sirva este post, si que la vida es mas facil con pivot, pero esta es una alternativa cuando no puedes usar pivot en mysql.